# How to sort the order of edges while printing the edge attributes of a Networkx graph

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I'm trying to print the edge attributes of a Networkx graph in a sorted manner.

For instance,

```
print(sorted(G.edges(data=True))
```

will display an ordered dict

```
[(3, 7, OrderedDict([('w1', 9.62), ('w2', 37.2)])), (3, 8, OrderedDict([('w1', 9.42), ('w2', 49.6)]))]
```

Likewise, I want to print a single attribute ( only `w1` or `w2`, data=True prints both) as a sorted output.

Example, when I try

```
print(sorted(nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'w1').values()))
```

doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to display sorted output of a single attribute will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nx.get_edge_attributes` will only return the actual attrubutes. Probably the simples way could be to keep only one of the attributes from the result of `G.edges(data=True)`:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(3, 8, w1= 9.62, w2=37.2)
G.add_edge(3, 7, w1= 9.42, w2=49.6)

attr = 'w1'
sorted(((*edge, (attr, d[attr])) for *edge, d in G.edges(data=True)))
# [(3, 7, ('w1', 9.42)), (3, 8, ('w1', 9.62))]
```